# Beginner guide / Flash to Android converter

Tags: android

I am new in the Android development area ( i bought my Samsung Galaxy S 2 days ago, mainly to test the apps I create directly on the device ) and today I started gathering information about how to create Android Apps ( I`m interested in creating games ) .

I have installed the SDK Tools and Eclipse , updated everything , and already started on my first app .

The problem is that I try to convert my Flash games I previously made , I try to convert them into Android games .
Is there an easy way to do this ? I'm a fast learner , but complete beginner to Android apps/games .

Can someone give me some tips / link to tutorials they found useful / hints / help / code snippets ?
Maybe someone can help me by telling me how they started , or how they start the games now ?

I'm asking here because all the tutorials I've read were for Apps , none for games .

Thank you in advance .
Chris

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck at gamedev.stackexchange.com for game specific questions.

However, if you want to develop in the Android SDK, there are a few game specific examples in the Android documentation, i.e. [LunarLander](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html).  I would read through the SDK documentation thoroughly before you do anything else.

If you just want to run your flash game on Android directly, see [Air for Android](http://blogs.adobe.com/air/2010/04/adobe_air_applications_for_and.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also build with AIR captive runtime so user don't get any notification to install or update AIR runtime,but APK output will increase by ~9Mb.

Or you can give a try on [Andaired](http://swftoapk.en.softonic.com/)